# Tengo un problema con este codigo, podrian ayudarme?

Tags: php

Este es el código `PHP` que estoy usando para agregar datos diferentes en diferentes tablas, pero cuando van a ingresar los datos a la base de datos se va en false

```php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "we"); 
//selección de la base de datos con la que vamos a trabajar 
$cedula = $_POST['cedula'];
$fecha_nacimiento = $_POST['fecha_nacimiento'];
$valor_credito = $_POST['valor_credito'];
$nombre_seguro = "Seguro de Vida Credito Protegido";
$fecha_ges = "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP";


function execute($cedula, $fecha_nacimiento, $valor_credito, $nombre_seguro, $fecha_ges) 
{ 
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "we");
    $q1= "INSERT INTO clientes (cedula, fecha_nacimiento) values ('$cedula', '$fecha_nacimiento')"; 
    mysqli_query($conn, $q1); 
    $errores = mysqli_error($conn); 

    $q2= "INSERT INTO seguro_vida_pro (valor_credito, nombre_seguro, fecha_ges,) values ('$valor_credito', '$nombre_seguro', '$fecha_ges')"; 
    mysqli_query($conn, $q2); 
    $errores = mysqli_error($conn); 
    return $errores; 
} 

$result = execute($cedula, $fecha_nacimiento, $valor_credito, $nombre_seguro, $fecha_ges); 

if ($result > 0) { 
    echo "Todo Ok"; 
}  
else 
{ 
    echo "Error al insertar datos";
}
```

Siempre se va false y arroja "error al insertar datos"

Comment: tu funcion execute retorna los errores, osea que estas almacendando en $result los errores,  es decir cuando pones `if ($result >0)` estas preguntando si hay algun error.. entonces cuando no hay errores te salta el else.. cambialo por `if($result <= 0)` y quedara

Answer (score 0):

Ya que tu funcion excecute retorna los errores

```
$errores = mysqli_error($conn); 
return $errores;
```

cuando todo salga bien en la consulta, ese valor sera 0
y cuando haces el if

```
if ($result > 0) { 
   echo "Todo Ok"; 
}
```

te arrojara "Todo Ok" cuando hayan errores

cambialo por

```
if ($result <= 0) { 
echo "Todo Ok"; 
}  
else 
{ 
echo "Error al insertar datos";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En realidad `$errores` -al sobreescribir el primero- contiene el mensaje de error del segundo insert, que en caso de ser exitoso regresara una cadena vacía, la cual equivale en una *comparación flexible* a FALSE, cero ó NULL, y por lo tanto no será mayor a cero.

Comment: es cierto se me paso eso xd